# Orderby json field in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json

I have a json string stored in a sql table. The reason I am doing this is to output saved models, though I do not know what the models look like. It's meant to be a plugin.

They are separated by type though. For example I will use a form model.

One form will have a `firstname, lastname, email, and comment`. 
Another form will have a `fullname, email, comment, and phonenumber`.

I don't want to force someone to use a specific model that cannot be changed easily.

I have my two models displaying perfectly in two separate html tables. I'm only saying this so you know every one will have the same attributes depending on the type and the two models will never be in the same html table.

I simply want the ability to order by unknown attributes that are in the json. Is there a way to sortby a keyvalue in the json string in SQL Server?

I would do it after it makes the query, however the problem I face is I potentially will have hundreds of thousands of records. I do not want to make that large of a query and spit that JSON on my page, so I have implemented paging. I feel there has got to be a good way to do this.

I am using asp.net if it matters.

Comment: What are the sort criteria and what are a few samples that would need to be sorted?

Comment: That's actually why I'm saving it into the database like this. I'm not sure what the fields are. It's to store random models. I honestly would use a nosql database for this, but I cannot do this currently.

Comment: The sort criteria could be one of any of the attributes, or since it's json keys.

Comment: It isn't json however. It's just a json-formatted string. The database has no concept of key here bSo unless you just intend to do random full text search I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: If you want SQL to do the job, use SQL entites (it's pretty real to encode flexible structures in SQL). Don't ask an SQL server to handle a format it gives absolutely no damn about.

Comment: FYI, support for JSON is planned for SQL Server 2016 according to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx).

Comment: @BrianRogers ["Every program attempts to expand until it can read mail."](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zawinskis-Law.html) [And it's not necessarily a good thing.](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm not making any judgements; just pointing out that there are apparently plans to support JSON.  You can do with that what you will.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want SQL to do the job, use SQL entites (it's pretty real to encode flexible structures in SQL). Don't ask an SQL server to handle a format it gives absolutely no damn about.

Comment: A simple, "no, there's no way to do this" would suffice :)  Sometimes that's just the answer.

Comment: @sgress454 Wrong. The message is: there is _a_ way (reimplement a JSON parser in whatever-SQL), but it's not the way to go.

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as correct.I'm just going to do it client side for now and come up with a more effective solution soon. Maybe use a NoSQL DB

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily condescending. It's also wrong, judging by the solution offered in [Jovan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553297/4782863).

Answer (score 8):

In SQL Server 2016 you can use JSON fields in the regular queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM mytab
WHERE JSON_VALUE(json_col, '$.lastname') LIKE '%Connor%'
ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(json_col, '$.firstname')
```

You can even create indexes on properties. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921890.aspx) for more examples. This feature will be available in Azure SQL Database too.
In older versions you will need to use some kind of CLR assembly that parses JSON.